# jQuery - Progress Bar and Pagination depending on what element is shown and how many elemtns

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, pagination

I need to find out how to create a progress bar and pagination for my contact form using jQuery.

Each section of my form is split into list elements for eg.

```
<form>
<ul>
<li class="section1 shown">
<label>label</label>
<input type="text"/>
</li>
<li class="section2 current">
<label>label</label>
<input type="text"/>
</li>
<li class="section3">
<label>label</label>
<input type="text"/>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="arrow"></div>
</form>
```

When the page loads initially, section1 is only visible until the arrow is clicked which then shows section2 and so on. I need to develop a jQuery script which count's the number of sections in total and also counts the number of li elements up to and including the current class. This will then output a pagination, for eg. 2/3 and a progress bar eg. width:66.6%;

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, from this answer I have worked out how to do it.

```
var totalStageNumber = $('li').length;
var currentStageNumber = $('li.completed').length + $('li.current').length;
var progressBar = 100 / (totalStageNumber) * ((currentStageNumber) - 1) ;

$('.number-total').text('' + totalStageNumber + '');
$('.number-current').text('' + currentStageNumber + '');

$('.simform .progress').css({'width':progressBar + '%'});


$('div.next').on('click', function(){
    var currentStageNumber = $('li.completed').length + $('li.current').length;
    $('.number-current').text('' + currentStageNumber + '');

    var progressBar = 100 / (totalStageNumber) * ((currentStageNumber) - 1);
    $('.simform .progress').css({'width':progressBar + '%'});
});

<form>
<ul class="simform">
<li class="section1 shown">
<label>label</label>
<input type="text"/>
</li>
<li class="section2 current">
<label>label</label>
<input type="text"/>
</li>
<li class="section3">
<label>label</label>
<input type="text"/>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="controls">
<div class="progress"></div>
<div class="number-current"></div> / <div class="number-total"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

The Progress bar shows what boxes have been filled in and not what stage the user is on unlike the pagination

I have turned this form http://tympanus.net/Development/MinimalForm/ into jquery

Answer (score -1):

you can you event cssClassChanged
example:

```
$('li').bind('cssClassChanged', data, function(){ 
  var progressBarWidth = $('li.shown').size() / $('li').size();
});
```